# Adding functional buttons when new elements are added

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working on the classic shopping list problem that people encounter when first learning JavaScript. So I am able to add new elements to the list just fine, but when I try to delete those items using the delete button, those won't be deleted.

Neither does the toggle button work. Can someone help?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li> Notebook <button class="Delete">Delete!</button></li>
        <li>Jello <button class="Delete">Delete!</button></li> 
        <li>Spinach <button class="Delete">Delete!</button></li>
        <li>Rice <button class="Delete">  Delete!</button></li>
        <li>Birthday Cake <button class="Delete"> Delete!</button></li>
        <li>Candles <button class="Delete"> Delete!</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript, I cannot figure out what the problem is:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("Delete");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete!"));
    button.classList.add("Delete")

    li.appendChild(button);


}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}



button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++){
 li[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}
function liClick(){
  this.classList.toggle("done");
}



input.value = "";
for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++){
    li[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}
function liClick(){
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i ++){
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener("click", deleteItem)
}
function deleteItem(){
    this.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in creating dynamic content is that when you add an element, this element is naked, meaning without any event listeners. the event listeners you added in the code to the **existing** buttons, will not pass to the new buttons, you need to bind the new buttons again. more generally, event listeners are bound to specific elements, and not to a general idea like button. your solution is pretty simple, just run the binding again after the element creation. hope I helped

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new to this. How do I bind it?

Comment: you already have the code. just add button.addEventListener("click", deleteItem) at the end of the createListElement function